# How can I find polygons within the radius of selected polygon in python?

Tags: python, gis, polygon, qgis, radius

I am trying to find nearest polygon to my selected polygon within a radius of circle (in a buffer).
It can be done in Qgis with select features by radius operator but I don't know how to perform it in python jupyter notebook.
I would be thankful if you kindly help me in this regard.